# Why is pygame.blit() reseting back to 0 after 65500 pixels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Im creating a program that will show every image from a folder, i created a function for scrolling because in case there were a lot of images it wouldn't fit the screen, the problem is that after reaching 65536 on the y value, it will start bliting at 0 again, like placing the new names on top of the old ones.

This is a preview code that recreates my problem, what should happen when you press a key is a black screen or maybe a little of green on top, what really happens is that the top half is the y = 0 and the bottom half is y = -65540

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
colors = pygame.Surface((50,66000))#73825
colors.fill("green", (0,33, 50, 65600))
x = 0
running = True
while running:
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)
    screen.fill("black")
    screen.blit(colors, (225,x))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            x = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            x = -65540
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

this only happens when using blit as rects work perfectly beyond the 65k pixel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it wouldn't fit the screen, the problem is that after reaching **65536**

**65535** is 0xffff, which is the maximum number that can be represented by 2 bytes or a variable of type "uint16". Likely this is the internal data type pygame uses to represent a pixel on the screen or the size of a `pygame.Surface`. This is far enough for any display in the world.
It is not a good idea to create a `pygame.Surface` of this size. It would be better to draw the parts of the images on the screen that should be displayed in each frame.

---

Minimal example of a scrollable image grid of images of the same size:

```py
import pygame, random, math

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
scr_w, scr_h = screen.get_size()

img_w, img_h = 300, 200
images = []
for i in range(98):
    img = pygame.Surface((img_w, img_h))
    img.fill([random.randrange(256) for _ in range(3)])
    images.append(img)

columns = 10
rows = math.ceil(len(images) / columns)
offset_x = 0
offset_y = 0

def fill_display():
    row = offset_y // img_h
    display_y = (img_h - (offset_y % img_h)) - img_h
    while display_y < scr_w:
        col = offset_x // img_w
        display_x = (img_w - (offset_x % img_w)) - img_w
        while display_x < scr_h:
            i = row * columns + col
            if i < len(images):
                screen.blit(images[i], (display_x, display_y))
            display_x += img_w
            col += 1
        display_y += img_h
        row += 1

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    offset_x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * 20
    offset_y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * 20
    offset_x = min((columns) * img_w - scr_w, max(0, offset_x))
    offset_y = min((rows) * img_h - scr_h, max(0, offset_y))

    screen.fill("black")
    fill_display()
    pygame.display.update()
```